# Tensorflow: Replacing Placeholders With Real Tensors In A Restored Metagraph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

(I'm on TF 1.7 right now, in case that matters.)

I'm trying to initialize and then save a model and associated metagraph in one script (`init.py`) so that I can load the model and resume training from a second script (`train.py`). The model is initialized with placeholders for training example and label, to be replaced with real tensors during training. Yet when I try create some real tensors in `train.py` (from a Dataset), I get a stack trace to the effect that my iterator hasn't been initialized. The trace points to the `import_meta_graph()` call and happens the same whether I use a oneshot iterator (which shouldn't require initialization) or an initializable iterator which I *am* actually initializing.

Am I missing something, conceptually, for how two graphs get spliced together?

I want to believe that this is a common use case for saving and restoring metagraphs, but I can't find any examples of it on the internet. How do others feed their real data into a restored model?

```
Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext_1', defined at:
  File "src/tictactoe/train.py", line 47, in <module>
    meta_graph, input_map={'example': example, 'label': label})
  File "/home/mason/dev/rust/seraphim/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1927, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/mason/dev/rust/seraphim/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 741, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/home/mason/dev/rust/seraphim/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mason/dev/rust/seraphim/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 577, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mason/dev/rust/seraphim/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/mason/dev/rust/seraphim/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed because theiterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext_1 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,19], [?,9]], output_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator_1)]]
```

Complete code of both scripts here:

```
# init.py

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from pathlib import Path

import argparse
import os
import tensorflow as tf

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Initialize a TicTacToe expert model.')
parser.add_argument('name', metavar='foo-model', help='Model prefix')
args = parser.parse_args()
model_dir = "src/tictactoe/saved_models/" + args.name + "/" + args.name

with tf.Session() as sess:
    example = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=[1, 9 * 2 + 1], name ='example')
    label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 9], name='label')
    dense = tf.layers.dense(tf.cast(example, tf.float32), units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(dense, units=9, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='softmax')
    tf.add_to_collection('softmax', softmax)

    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.group(
        tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
        tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init)

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=label, predictions=softmax)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.01)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')
    tf.add_to_collection('train', train)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saved = saver.save(sess, model_dir, global_step=0)
    print("Model saved in path: %s" % saved)
```

Here's the training script.

```
# train.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from pathlib import Path
import argparse
import glob
import os
import tensorflow as tf

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Initialize a TicTacToe expert model.')
parser.add_argument('name', metavar='foo-model', help='Model prefix')
args = parser.parse_args()

model_dir = "src/tictactoe/saved_models/" + args.name 
saver_prefix = "src/tictactoe/saved_models/" + args.name + "/" + args.name

latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)
meta_graph = ".".join([latest_checkpoint, "meta"])

num_epochs = 100
minibatch_size = 128
dataset_dir = "src/tictactoe/gamedata"
def make_dataset(minibatch_size, dataset_dir):
    files = glob.glob("{}/*.tfrecord".format(dataset_dir))
    print(files)
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(minibatch_size)
    return dataset

def parse(bytes):
  features = {"game": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
              "choice": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), tf.float32, allow_missing=True)}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(bytes, features)
  game = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features["game"], tf.uint8)
  choice =  parsed_features["choice"]
  return tf.reshape(game, [19]), tf.reshape(choice, [9])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    dataset = make_dataset(minibatch_size, dataset_dir)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    example, label = iterator.get_next()    

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
        meta_graph, input_map={'example': example, 'label': label})
    print("{}".format(meta_graph))
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
    print("{}".format(latest_checkpoint))
    train_op = tf.get_collection('train_op')[0]

    for i in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                sess.run(train_op)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
            print(saver.save(sess, saver_prefix, global_step=step))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the issue. The issue is that my Saver in `train.py` is saving the real input tensors that I've mapped in. When I try to restore, those real input tensors are restored from the disk, but not initialized.

So: after running `input.py` one time, the following `train.py` script successfully trains. But when I run again, the extra input tensors that it's mapped into the graph are restored but not initialized. It's a bit strange because I am mapping them out again  when I restore, so I wouldn't think it'd be necessary to initialize them. I found that `tf.report_uninitialized_variables()` was crucial for debugging the issue.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from pathlib import Path
import argparse
import glob
import os
import tensorflow as tf

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Initialize a TicTacToe expert model.')
parser.add_argument('name', metavar='foo-model', help='Model prefix')
args = parser.parse_args()

model_dir = "src/tictactoe/saved_models/" + args.name 
saver_prefix = "src/tictactoe/saved_models/" + args.name + "/" + args.name

latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)
meta_graph = ".".join([latest_checkpoint, "meta"])

num_epochs = 100
minibatch_size = 128
dataset_dir = "src/tictactoe/gamedata"
def make_dataset(minibatch_size, dataset_dir):
    files = glob.glob("{}/*.tfrecord".format(dataset_dir))
    print(files)
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(minibatch_size)
    return dataset

def parse(bytes):
  features = {"game": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
          "choice": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), tf.float32, allow_missing=True)}


parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(bytes, features)
  game = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features["game"], tf.uint8)
  choice =  parsed_features["choice"]
  return tf.reshape(game, [19]), tf.reshape(choice, [9])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    dataset = make_dataset(minibatch_size, dataset_dir)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    example, label = iterator.get_next()    
    # print("before iterator", sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph, input_map={'example': example, 'label': label})
    print("{}".format(meta_graph))
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
    print("{}".format(latest_checkpoint))

    train_op = tf.get_collection('train_op')[0]
    init = tf.get_collection('init')[0]

    for i in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                sess.run(train_op)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
            print(saver.save(sess, saver_prefix))
```